# ASP.NET BeginReceiveFrom send control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, udp

I try to create a udp server. I would like to modify a text box from a web form from the function call from BeginReceiveFrom. For the moment the function recognizes the textbox but does not change the textbox web form

```
public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{ 
    private TextBox tbConsole;
    public AsynchronousSocketListener(TextBox ptbConsole)
    {
        tbConsole = ptbConsole;
        StartListening();            
    }
    public  void StartListening()
    {
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);           
        ...
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.dataStream, 0, this.dataStream.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender
                , new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), epSender);
    }
    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ...
        tbConsole.Text = "sended";
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Has this been solved with the other answer?

Comment: Yes thanks, I used Ajax for update my view

Comment: Very good. I suggest you delete this then.