# WebForm: Update textbox from another thread

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, webforms

In WebForm, How Update textbox from another thread

```
lock (tbConsole)
{
    tbConsole.Text += "\r\n server:" + text; 
}
```

Comment: best threading tutorial http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx

Comment: Why do you need a separate thread for that?

Comment: Please, see my previous post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448956/asp-net-beginreceivefrom-send-control , I don't knwon how change my textbox from behind code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't.

Code Behind is executed on the server, then the resulting Page is sent to the client/browser. At that point, the life cycle of your C# Code Behind is over.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Invoke method of the control to run the code on the UI thread:

```
tbConsole.Invoke(new Action(() => tbConsole.Text += "\r\n server:" + text));
```

Comment: There is not Invoke for WebControl